# Unreal Engine Movie Render Queue Plugin

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, plugin

I am developing a plugin to stylize videos and images rendered through Movie Render Queue. What I want to do now is capture the image processed by Movie Render Queue at runtime and stylize the images one by one and encode it into a movie. Which C++ API can be used to capture the images from Movie Render Queue at runtime (while rendering) not on disk?

Answer (score 0):

To capture images from a rendering program like Movie Render Queue at runtime, you can use a C++ API such as OpenCV. OpenCV is a popular, open-source library for computer vision tasks, and it includes a range of functions for capturing, processing, and encoding images and video.

Here is an example of how you could use OpenCV to capture an image from Movie Render Queue and stylize it:

```html
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Initialize a capture object to grab frames from Movie Render Queue
  VideoCapture capture(0);

  // Check if the capture object was initialized successfully
  if (!capture.isOpened()) {
    cout << "Failed to initialize capture" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  // Create a window to display the stylized images
  namedWindow("Stylized", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

  // Loop until the capture is stopped
  while (true) {
    // Grab a frame from the capture
    Mat frame;
    capture >> frame;

    // Check if the frame was grabbed successfully
    if (frame.empty()) {
      cout << "Failed to grab frame" << endl;
      break;
    }

    // Stylize the frame here...

    // Display the stylized frame
    imshow("Stylized", frame);

    // Wait for a key press to continue
    int key = waitKey(1);
    if (key != -1) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In this example, the VideoCapture object is initialized with a capture index of 0 to grab frames from the default video input (e.g. the webcam). You can specify a different index or a file path to capture from a specific video source.

The capture >> frame line grabs a frame from the capture, and the imshow() function displays the frame in a window. The waitKey() function is used to pause the program until a key is pressed, which allows you to view the stylized frames one by one.

You can use the various functions in the OpenCV library to stylize the frames as you wish, and then use the VideoWriter class to encode the stylized frames into a movie file. For more information and examples, you can refer to the OpenCV documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/master/